# How to use the finish() method in Android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, activity-finish

As a newcomer to Android development, I would like to learn how to terminate an activity in Android. I have completed one project already and the previous activity functioned properly. Could you please explain how to finish that activity quickly when the next activity begins?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, do you want Activity A to start a new Activity B, and for Activity A to finish?

Comment: I agree with dave.c and further more, why would you want to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After I start the activity, I call the finish() method:

```
Intent i=new Intent(mainclass.this,nextclass.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Then the previous activity(mainclass) is finished.

Comment: What happens if u don't call the finish function? Does it really make a difference in foreground? Ty

Comment: The problem could be the question, but I don't recommend this code because you shouldn't need to call startActivity and finish at the same period. `startActivity` sends you to the next screen and `finish` will send you back to the previous screen. I tested this code and while it did result in "nextclass" being called, it resulted in an infinite loop when using the back button.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to add my own answer to this question because it is closed. 

If you wish to go back to the previous activity, see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

If you wish to continue to the next activity, please use this code:
`Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.class, NextActivity.class); startActivity(i)`

Comment: Also see this documentation for the finish method of Activity: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish