# Can an Activity call its own onPause(), onStop()?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

My app interfaces with a Bluetooth peripheral. When the peripheral wants to shut down, can I clean up the app simply by calling my Activity's own `onPause()` and `onStop()` methods? Is the fact that they call the superclass's methods likely to cause any problems?

The idea would be to call `finish()` after that.

Comment: If you just call `finish()` all of the appropriate lifecycle methods (onPause, onStop, onDestroy) will be called.  It is not recommended to call those lifecycle methods directly.

Comment: You *can*, but I would recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, you can. What you should be asking is "Should I"? Which the answer is no.

Like you've mentioned, since they do call the superclass methods, there is some extra Android OS cleanup magic that happens. It may result in a successful case once in a while, but it's not guaranteed. There is a lot of things that happen in the backround that you don't want to fool with. Don't reinvent the wheel.

If there is code that is ran within the `onPause` and `onStop` methods that you would like to use elsewhere, I would create a function called `cleanupBluetooth` and the `onPause` and `onStop` would call and anywhere else it needs to.

If you need to actually call the `onPause` and `onStop` methods because you need to stop and halt the activity, you can do that by calling `finish()` ([how to use finish()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595025/how-to-use-the-finish-method-in-android)). The `finish()` method will call the appropriate Android OS magic that's needed to be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can call them manually, but you shouldn't let Android do it itself when it needs to. If you wish to call those activities, you are likely not really wanting the activity any more, so you can just call finish and then android will call the relevant methods based on the activities life cycle.

You can find more info about the activity life cycle by going [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: Thanks. Very familiar with the lifecycle docs but didn't see my question specifically addressed.

Answer (score 0):

OnPause() is also a method in your activity and it will likely normal method. It overrides method of activity and you can call it from anywhere in activity and from interface also.