# Going Two Activities back?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this Activities sequence:
`Avtivity01 => Avtivity02 => Avtivity03`

You can go from `Avtivity01` to `Avtivity02` after you click a button.

You can go from `Avtivity02` to `Avtivity03` after you click a button.

-

I want to go from `Activity03` to `Activity01` **DIRECTLY** after I click a button.

-

**NOTE:**

I do NOT want to use `Intent`, because I want to have `Activity01` **as if I pressed the back button from `Activity02`**

How to do that, please?

Comment: Remove Activity 2 from Activity stack , by calling finish on Activity2 when trasitioning to Activity3.

Comment: calling finish(),on which method of Activity2?

Comment: by removing it, I'll NOT be able to reach it if I press the back button on `Activity03`

Comment: @Rasel, In the method where he calls for Activity3 , startActivity(Activity3); finish();

Comment: @iturki -- oops ! ok , I thought onBack you want to go to activity1 from activity3! On clicking a button, then you will have to use Intents.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Why can't you use an `Intent`?  You can use the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) when you click the button.  **Edit:** If you want to preserve the original instance of the `Activity`, you can use this flag in conjunction with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).

Do you ever want to be able to press a button from Activity03 to go back to Activity02? If you ALWAYS want it to go back to Activity01, you could alternatively use `android:noHistory="true"` on Activity02 in the manifest and just call `finish()` on Activity03.

Comment: I want to keep Activity02 so that when I press the back button in Activity02, I can reach it. Also, I want to reach Activity01 directly from Activity03. I can't use Intent because it will start Activity01 as if it is new. I want to start it as if it is opened before (i.e. as if I clicked the back button from activity02). I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Yes, you can use an `Intent` exactly like I said.  That's how it's done.  The flag finishes all activities on top of the one you're starting.

Comment: It didn't ! It starts Activity01 from scratch

Comment: What are you trying to do? Save information that you have changed during the life of Activity01? If you want it to use the already-running instance, read the link that I posted and use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in conjunction with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

Comment: I read the link and I used both flags. And I got the same result

Comment: It works now!!! For some reason it didn't at the first try. thanks for your help. Please update your question by mentioning both flags so that I accept it. Thanks again :)

Comment: this is correct answer. of course don't forget to add this code in manifest `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Answer (score 7):

You can go back more than one screen to which ever screen you need using intent and use flags to prevent going back to same screen :

```
Intent gotoScreenVar = new Intent(goFromScreenCls.this, goToScreenCls.class);

gotoScreenVar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(gotoScreenVar);
```

Answer (score 6):

I was had the same problem,

Short answer is add this line to intent.

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

Long answer is:

I have `MainActivity`, `SecondActivity` and `ThirdActivity` what i want to do is opening `SecondActivity` from `MainActivity` and then `ThirdActivity` from `SecondActivity` and i want to click a button in the `ThirdActivity` that close both of `SecondActivity` and `ThirdActivity` without calling a new `MainActivity` i want it to functional as i back to it not creating a new one And the most thing i need is to keep back button functional normal in the `ThirdActivity` to back to `SecondActivity` if i need to change some of my choices in the `SecondActivity` so i can't call `finish();` in the `SecondActivity` after starting `ThirdActivity` or any other solutions like `android:noHistory="true"` in the `SecondActivity` manifest because those solutions kill the `SecondActivity` and i can't go back to it throw back button.

so this flag solve the problem for me `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

> **FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT**
>
> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause the >launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it >is already running.

go to reference [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

so i tried this code to go back my `MainActivity` from `ThirdActivity` when i click the button in `ThirdActivity` . i hope this will help you.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

[link](https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/tag/flag_activity_single_top/) has good article. This will help you. By the way you can use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can override Back button click on Activity3

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        startActivity(Activity3.this,Activity1.class);
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Read the question carefully. `I want to keep the back button behavior` in Activity03. I just want to have a button on it that perform two backs

Comment: can't you just call the Activity1 using that button

Comment: It will start as a fresh activity. I want it to start `as if I clicked the back button from Activity02`

Answer (score -2):

It will work with just one line.
after calling your third activity call `finish()` to next line. and it will work.

eg.
In your Activity02

```
Intent thirdActivity = new Intent(this,Activity03.class);
startActivity(thirdActivity);
finish();
```

Comment: I NEED to keep Activity02. Please read the comments under the question.