# Return back to previous screen in Android?

Tags: java, android, button

possible duplicate of [How to close activity and go back to previous activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393899/how-to-close-activity-and-go-back-to-previous-activity-in-android)

The problem is, I add finish() at the end of the method I'm currently on, and the whole app closes.

I want it to return back to the previous screen by pressing the back button on the phone (I don't want to add a back button in the app)

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void secondScreen(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);
    }
```

I want to return to main from secondScreen()

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do here. You have a setContentView method set to activity_main(which I assume is your launching activity). In addition to that, you have method secondScreen and you have called a setContentView set to layout of second activity. Can you please post a complete source code(both activities) for more clarity?

Comment: Acitity_main is just a screen with a Image button, and activity_second_screen just has three normals buttons in it. Do you still need the source code for them?

Comment: So in a single activity, you are switching to a second activity by just changing the contentView which activates when you click on the Image button. Am I right? The main purpose of my asking for the source code is to see how are you going from main activity to second activity

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Then your implementation is not a possible duplication of the link you provided in your post, as that example has two different activities. Please refer to codeMagic's reply below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you only have one `Activity` and you are just changing the `layout` with `setContentView()`. While you could fix this by overriding `onBackPressed()` and changing the `layout` there, this is not recommended. If you want to separate `layout`s then you should have two separate `Activities`. So you should create a second `Activity` as you did with the first and in the `onCreate()` you would have `setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);`

Then in your, I'm guessing it is, `onClick()` you would use an `Intent` to go to that second `Activity`.

```
public void secondScreen(View v) {
    Intenet i = new Intent(v.getContext(), NextActivityName.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

[Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

[Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I'm getting an error when I click on activity_main image button. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/qbMwdnKx

Comment: That doesn't appear to be all of your logcat

Comment: Just as it says, you need to declare it in your `manifest.xml` as you have your first `Activity`. [Manifest Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)