# How to kill an Android activity

Tags: java, android

I have an application with three activities. FirstActivity, SecondActivity, ThirdActivity.

In FirstActivity there is a button, which starts SecondActivity. In SecondActivity, there are two ways to go to the ThirdActivity. But there is one method with a code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
```

Both variants use this code snippet.

1. This code runs in a +- 12 seconds automatically
2. In `onBackPressed()` method

And here is my problem: when user press Back, ThirdActivity opens, but in a few seconds ThirdActivity opens again from the first variant.

So, how to fully kill an Activity, so it won't start another activity for two times?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close activity and go back to previous activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393899/how-to-close-activity-and-go-back-to-previous-activity-in-android)

Comment: Did you use handler for run code after 12 sec ?

Comment: @AmirK.Zarini yes! Is it a problem?

Comment: @HarisDautović thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately I have not found solution for my problem there.

Comment: @Laughing_Man Yes, You must cancel it if you not need it anymore with handler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable).
When you start ThirdActivity from onBackPressed instead handler, remove your future task to stop running anymore.

Comment: @AmirK.Zarini your comment helped me! I've stopped my hadler using removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); Thank you! You could write an answer, and I would accept it.

Comment: @Laughing_Man OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cancel your future task if you not need it anymore with

```
handler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable)
```

When you start ThirdActivity from onBackPressed instead handler

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try calling `finish()` after starting the activity maybe that will help I'm not sure though like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it does not help. I've used a debugger, and program runs this method twice.

Comment: @Laughing_Man The code given in answer will work correctly.