# WRITE_SETTINGS intent closing after getting permission

Tags: android, android-intent, settings, android-permissions, system-setting

I want to close the WRITE_SETTINGS permission intent as the user allows the permission. I have seen some apps doing this like getting permission and closing the intent automatically.

How I can achieve this functionality?

Comment: I don't really understand, do you have an example pls ?

Comment: I don't remeber the name of apps but I have seen that like when ask for the runtime permission for write settings permission we have to open intent. I want to close that intent when user allow the permission.

Comment: I will search in this way ;)

Comment: Have you ever succeeded in creating the intent you want?
maybe this post can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393899/how-to-close-activity-and-go-back-to-previous-activity-in-android