# How to unload activity in android

Tags: android, activity-finish

I want to unload activity .Actually i have three buttons one for login ,proceed and last for logout.when we login home page is appears and when we click on logout then once again login form should appears but problem is this when we logout then all the activity except login activity should destroyed .So please suggest me how to do this.Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have done. This looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: Learn managing activity in android. see activity features : finish startActivity , intent flags like cleartop and so on.. after that you will have an idea how to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activities are managed in a stack in android. What you need to do is to go back in activity stack. You could call `finishActivity()`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity) is another thead.

Comment: Finally i used this code and its working fine                               @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onBackPressed();
  this.finish();
 }

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

One way is Before launching new activity,you better call finish(). It will close current activity and you can open new activity. On clicking logout, you just call intent which shows login form.

If you learn how to manage activities in stack, then u can achieve this in different way.