# Go back to Previous Application (not Activity) in Android

Tags: android

There are two Android applications calling each other: App1, App2.

steps:

1. start App1 from Android desk. -->
2. start startActivity(intent) or startActivityForResult(intent,0) to App2 from App1. -->
3. start startActivity(intent) or startActivityForResult(intent,0) again to App1 from App2. -->
4. start  ( ? )  to go back to app1(activity) or App2.

I woud like make a dialog to let user to choice  back to App1 or App2 in step 4. Is it possible to complete it ?

I have had tried the [article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity) and it just back to the activity on App1 only.

Thanks for any suggestion !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override [`onActivityResults`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) of the activity in App1, and if the user chooses App2, simply call `finish` on the activity.

Comment: Binyamin, thanks for your quick feed back. And I will try the soulution today to see if it can meet the expections.

Comment: There was the OnActivityResults method existed in App1 for other calling intent use. But, not on App2. Should I add and override onActivityResults on App2 too ?

Comment: Depends on which app gets the result from step 4.