# How can I show a previous view without startActivity();?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Go back to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity)

I need go to previous activity without startActivity because I don't want open again the activity. Can I choose putting up or down activity according I need?

Thank's!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `finish()`.

Your activity will be closed and you will return to your previous activity.