# Jump back to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Go back to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity)

How do I jump back to the previous activity in Android? How do I find which one is the previous activity?

Comment: Possible [duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4038479/1050058)

Comment: Extreme lack of research effort...

Answer (score 5):

To go back to previous activity call `finish()` in your current activity.

When you call `finish()`, the resulting activity which is resuming will be your previous activity.

For more details study the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). It will give you a better idea of activity and navigation between the activities...

Answer (score -1):

And, If you have not invoked finish() on your previous activity. Just finish() the current activity, it automatically displays previous. (Not recommended because entire activity will be stored in memory.)

Comment: ohh ohh!! why?? who made it not useful!!??