# What is the purpose of using moveTaskToBack() method in android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using moveTaskToBack() method in my activity.

When I am pressing back button the activity still is visible. The back key does not work. What did I do wrong here? I want to navigate back to the previous activity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    new Finalizer().killApp(false);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: I can say it causes blank black screen for 1s when you are closing apk (if it was the last activity before exit of course).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The purpose of moveTaskToBack:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

> moveTaskToBack(boolean nonRoot)
>
> Move the task containing this activity to the back of the activity stack.

What you could do is:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true); // I don't think you're looking for this.
    new Finalizer().killApp(false); // Neither this.
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Maybe this: [Android: Go back to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity)
Something similar in your `onBackPressed()` after `super.OnBackPressed();`
Also make sure when you're hitting your back button, you're actually going in this method.

Answer (score 4):

If you call `super` it triggers the default implementation of back button, which just finishes the current activity.  Try removing the line `super.onBackPressed();` and then see if the new behavior is what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

### Before i update the code, when i want to close my app in these situations, something unexpected happen to me.

> Launch -> isSignIn(yes) -> `MainActivity` -> Press Back -> Close.

---

> Launch -> isSignIn(no) -> `SignInActivity` -> Press Back -> Close.

---

> Launch -> isSignIn(yes) -> `MainActivity` -> Press Sign Out ->
>   `SignInActivity` -> Press Back -> `SignInActivity` -> Press Back ->
>   `SignInActivity` (and so on loop and stuck on `SignInActivity` until i
>   press history/recent app/home button).

---

> Launch -> isSignIn(no) -> `SignInActivity` -> Press Sign In -> `MainActivity` ->
>   Press Sign Out -> `SignInActivity` -> Press Sign In -> `MainActivity` -> Press Back ->
>   `MainActivity` -> Press Back ->
>   `MainActivity` (and so on loop and stuck on `MainActivity` until i
>   press history/recent app/home button).

### Now i provide this code both on `SignInActivity` that has Sign In button and `MainActivity` that has Sign Out button.

```java
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        finish();
    }
```

It's now working fine on every situations. When i press Back, the application close.