# Activity doesn't fire the onStop event

Tags: java, android

**My code list as follow:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed");
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**My test result is:**

```
11-29 15:20:09.850  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onCreate

11-29 15:20:09.851  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onStart

11-29 15:20:09.852  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onResume

11-29 15:20:18.887  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onBackPressed

11-29 15:20:18.909  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onPause

11-29 15:20:19.718  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onStop

11-29 15:20:29.471  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onStart

11-29 15:20:29.471  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onResume

11-29 15:20:32.030  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onBackPressed

11-29 15:20:32.050  4626  4626 D MainActivity: onPause
```

**My Test Step:**

1. Enter any 3rd App's Ui;
2. Use eclipse to run or debug my app, then my app will cover the 3rd app and be shown on the top;
3. Then press back-key many times as quickly as I can and go to desktop (home launcher).

If the result has onStop, maybe your press not so quick and then try.

Now I want to know whether the activity is visuable, but sometimes the onStop can't be called, please help me. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Remove `moveTaskToBack(true);`**

**And add `super.onBackPressed();`**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed");
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**Edit**

In one second , let it not press for twice .

```
private long lastTime;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentTime - lastTime < 1000) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    } else {
        Log.e("TAG", "pressed again");
        lastTime = currentTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I want to reuse the activity which have some variables and states, so I just wan't to push it to background but not destroy it, thank you!

Comment: If you do want to reuse it .And you use `moveTaskToBack(true);` ,it just like you pressed `home button` .So it will not call `onStop` method .

Comment: If I pressed home button and onStop will be called, it's no problem

Comment: And you can look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197281/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-movetasktoback-method-in-android

Comment: I have seen the link, and it can't resolve my problem.

Comment: It's no problem when you pressed home button, but if you pressed back button like the test step,the onStop will not be called.

Comment: Could you try my edited ?Let the pressed for only once .

Comment: It may be android's bug .

Comment: May be .Sometimes the android will cause some strange bug.

Comment: So we can do this to prevent continuous press .You can try it .