# How to come back to activity after press ok button on web view page in android?

Tags: android, url, web-applications

when i press ok button after filled up form on web view page it should come back to activity in android.if any one have example sample code or logic  please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the following link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Comment: Is the activity the same where you load the webview or you load it on a new one?

Comment: show some code that you have tried so far or else explain your question a bit more.

Comment: @AlexBcn No Both are different activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <a href="url"></a> instead of button and make it look like button.

Code in your webpage <a href="android://back">Ok</a>

Code in Your Java file for Android Webview

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    private Context context;

    public MyWebViewClient(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.equals("android://back")){
              //to just close webview
              finish();  
             //to open another activity uncomment below code
             /* Intent i = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i); */
            return true;
        }
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
}
```