# Launch another application, return to previous application sometimes fails

Tags: android, memory

I have an application A with an activity that launches another application B as follow:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (launched == false) {
        Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(apk);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        startActivity(intent);
        launched = true;
    } else {
        // Here I launch another activity of application A
        launched = false;
    }
}
```

This other application B have a close button to finish its main activity.

The logic behavior is to return on the first application A in the `onResume()`'s "else".
Sometimes the `onDestroy()` method is called from my "launch" activity of the application A and the Android Desktop appears when application B stops.

My first thought is about the Android memory management. If the application B takes to much memory or if the Android GC turns itself on at this moment, the application A can be killed (Application A takes a lot of memory but it is another problem).

In the manifest, I put `android:persistent="true"` but it doesn't change anything.

Do you have any idea of how can I be sure to go back to application A when application B is over ?

EDIT:
When application B finish, the application A activity where I launched the application B doesn't go to `onResume()` but directly to `onStop()`. I thought it was like onStart -> onResume (here I launch application B) -> onPause (application B is now visible) -> onResume (it is the second time in onResume so the application B is over).

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should launch your first application from the onDestroy() of the second application.

Comment: I can't change the code of the application B if it was what you were thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`.
Be sure you don't lose state of calling activity, you need to save all pertinent data by overriding the `onSaveInstanceState` and adding data to the Bundle. Also override `onRestoreInstanceState` to handle when your activity come back and need to restore previous data.

Comment: It doesn't change anything (replacing `startActivity` by `startActivityForResult`). I just implement `onSaveInstanceState`/`onRestoreInstanceState` using the bundle to store my "launched" flag but nothing changes.

Comment: Implement `onActivityResult` method and (or) try to remove Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.

Comment: Indeed, without `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, the Activity Lifecycle is as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Returning to calling activity

[Android: Go back to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity)

Both `startActivityForResult` and `startActivity` can be used to call another activity. Note that `startActivityForResult` relies on the called activity to call `setResult` before it finishes.

#### Getting back to the activity in the right state

To "be sure", you can get back to application A in its state when you called B, you might have to persist its activity state, so that when application B returns, you can "recreate" it in the right state.

#### Quick Links:

[Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: You could just try calling own mini test application activity and see if it works. If it does, then it might be that Application B is faulty.

Comment: I'll try do do this. Anyway thanks for pointing the link about recreation in activity lifecycle.