# how to go back to previous activity with closing current activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can i go back to previous activity(List) with closing current activity(Save) in android
I tried the below code

```
public  void  cancel() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Save.this, List.class );
   startActivityForResult(intent, TIME_ENTRY_REQUEST_CODE);     
}
```

but while running unfortunately my app is stopped.. can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
public void cancel() {
  finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using startActivityForResult to start a activity , then you can use 
   finishActivity() to finish the activity and go back to the previous activity.
   To give you better understanding , i am adding  the following stack overflow link.

[Android:Go back to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity)

Code

```
public void gobacktoprious()
{
finishActivity();
}
```

Comment: If the answer helps you,then give me a upvote and accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this it handles when user clicks back key

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}