# How to return control to main activity (basic android app)

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm still quite new to android programming. I currently have a button on the home page that takes the user to a second activity. On the second activity, the user fills in two EditText boxes and clicks a button at the bottom of the page that should send information that the user entered with it. The button that returns to the main activity uses the following code:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

    String strData = "your data";

    EditText foodName = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.foodLabel));
    String foodNameString = foodName.getText().toString();

    returnIntent.putExtra("data", foodNameString);


    setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);        
    finish();
```

Where would I put code in my main activity that should run as soon as this button is clicked? And how can I access the information I sent back? Right now it returns to the main activity but does nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Comment: I understand how to go back, which is all this question shows. I want to know where to put a block of code in the main activity that will start running when I go back using information that was sent back

Answer (score 1):

If you expect a result from your second activity, you need to start second activity via [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) (not the `startActivity()`). In this case, once activity you launched is finished, Android will trigger `onActivityResult()` callback within your main activity. All the data you specified via `setResult()` will be passed in this callback