# Why cannot my activity recreate the previous one?

Tags: android, android-activity, savestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I have an `Activity`(A) which is downloading a file and putting the data(some book titles) from it into a `listView`. And from this `Activity`(A) i starter another `Activity`(B) which i can do some work with it. The problem is when i wanna back to `(A)` calling `this.finish()` using a button(from `B`), the file starts downloading again(although it has been downloaded).
I am using a `DownloadManager`to download the file and a `String[] book` to put the contents of the downloading file.
I tried to save my `Activity State`, like this(i don't want the file to be downloaded again):

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
   DownloadManager downloadManager = null;
   super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
   state.putStringArray("message", book);
   state.putParcelable("message1", (Parcelable) downloadManager);
}
```

And to recreate my `Activity`, i tried this(i don't want the file to be downloaded again):

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)) {
        book= savedInstanceState.getStringArray("message");
        downloadReference = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("message1");
    }
}
```

But the app crash when i wanna back from `B` to `A`. Any help or hints to show me how i can go from `B`to `A` without downloading the file each time is very welcome. Thanks in advance, Carl.

Comment: where you are writing this.finish() in which activity?

Comment: in `Activity B`. I'm using  a button `close` to close `B` and back to `A`.

Comment: hey just see this link you will get the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Comment: i tried this: `Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);` . But from `B` to `A` using just `finish()` i get the same problem (file being downloaded..)!!

Comment: when you are downloading file and is it changing activity or not just check

Comment: this is my onCreate(): `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadViews();
        connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiStatus();
    }` - `wifiStatus()`method check if wifi is `ON` --> `downloadFile()`, if `OFF`: wifi `ON` and `downloadFile()`.

Comment: `startActivityForResult` waits for callbacks when the started activity decided to finish. I'm not waiting something from the `child Activity`. I wanna just save the state of `A` when i go to `B`. And when i wanna back to `A` i find my saved state(without downloading again the file...)