# Android android:parentActivityName go to previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-manifest

When I press the arrow back I want to navigate to my previous screen(where I came from). So if I'm in MainActivity and go to setting I want the arrow to point back to MainActivity, but if I'm in another Activity I want it to go back to that activity.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/action_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
</activity>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Go back to previous activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity)

Comment: post your onBackPressed code

Comment: WHen you write "the arrow back" do you mean the hardware BACK button (at the bottom of the phone) or the soft arrow shown on the left side of the title bar?

Comment: @David Wasser Left side of the titlebar :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you start settings activity?

Just use `startActivity(intent)` in main activity and don't call `finish()` method. It should be handled automatically.

sample code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

just comment what's your problem exactly and I'll edit my answer.