# Android: How to go back previous Activity

Tags: android

I have four activities

- ListActivity
- Itemdetail_Activity
- record1_Act
- record2_act.

I can go from **ListActivity -> record1_Act** and from **ListActivity <-record1_Act** properly but when I want to go from **Itemdetail_Activity -> record2_act** and return back from **Itemdetail_Activity <- record2_act** it always goes **record2_act to ListActivity**.

I even used `i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);` but it does not work. How to solve this issues?

Here is my code

```
Intent i = new Intent(record2_act.this, Itemdetail_Activity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);

Intent i = new Intent(record1_Act.this, ListActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4038637/3843476) You may find your answer.

Comment: Please enter the correct flow which you desire. Or enter the whole code.

Comment: @DroidAks : I have Activity 1 , 2, 3, 4 i can go 1 -> 2 and 1 <-2 , And when i want to go 3 -> 4 and return back to 3 <- 4 here is the issue . 4 is always return to 1 means 1 <- 4 this is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After starting activity remove finish() call because it will clear that activity from stack and i see you have used finish in your code. also you do not need to set these flags.

Answer (score 0):

In activity 4, implement onBackPressed() as,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 Intent i = new Intent(4.this, 3.class);
 startActivity(i);
}
```

call this method if you have any back button. And if you want to link the backpress for every activity you need to implement onBackPressed() method in every activity.

Answer (score 0):

you can call **onBackPressed()** if previous activity not finished also you can use :

```
this.finish();
// Or
Activity currentActivity = this;
currentActivity.finish();
```

and if previous you finished activity you have to track user in activities and make list of activities, then move to :

```
activitiList.get(activityList.size() - 2);
// activityList.size() - 1 is last activity and activityList.size() - 2 is previous activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Do check if ItemDetailsActivity is NOT calling finish()