# Android title and home button as single back button

Tags: android, toolbar, title

How to achieve the same result as in standard android messaging application, where the back button is united with the title:
[image]

Comment: Would you consider using a custom toolbar view?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the button to go back to the previous activity/intent. If this isn't what you wanted, I'm not sure I understood your question properly.

Use [Android: Go back to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity) if that's what you wanted.

Comment: the question is how to make the back button have both image and title.

Comment: Well, I'm not an android expert yet, so I am not sure if the first suggestion will be possible; but it seems that there are two options. 1: put an image and text inside the button or 2: Make two buttons (one with the image and one with the text you want) and put them right next to each other using a linear layout or possibly even  overlap them (maybe absolute layout?)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/back"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:text="set_your_title"
android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/back"
android:textSize="24sp"/>
```

You can set the layout width according to your layout requirements.