# Android google map turn by turn navigation

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I am developing turn by turn navigation from current location to destination. I done this by using below code

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+address);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

The problem is that if click back in screen 1 it takes to screen 2. Then if i click back in screen 2 it takes to screen 3, then screen 4, then finally my activity.

What i want is if click back in screen 1, how can i take to my activity? how can i finish screen2, screen3, screen4 by clicking on back in screen1?

screen 1:

[image]

screen 2:

[image]

screen 3:

[image]

screen 4:

[image]

Comment: This? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4038637/697856

Comment: @selva_pollachi  Did u solve this issue? If it is pls share your code.

Comment: @Satheesh No. I didn't resolve this. Do u have any solution?

Comment: @selva_pollachi nope

Answer (score 1):

For this May be the Below Solution works i am not sure but let you try with this.

**Start the Screen 2,3 with android:noHistory="true" in its manifest entry.**

**Launch the Screen 4 with the Intent**

Comment: Please let me know weather it works or not. So willtry my best for this.

Comment: Thanks. These screens are present in library. Not in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Put to your intent the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP`

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="+address);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
mapIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_PREVIOUS_IS_TOP);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

`
From the android documentation:

> If set and this intent is being used to launch a new activity from an existing one, the current activity will not be counted as the top activity for deciding whether the new intent should be delivered to the top instead of starting a new one. The previous activity will be used as the top, with the assumption being that the current activity will finish itself immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Call intent like this in `Screenshot2.class, Screenshot3.class`

```
Intent in =new Intent(Screenshot2.this, Screenshot3.class);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(in);
```