# How to hard code the Back button?

Tags: android, button, back

I hid the action bar in my app and added an "ImageView" that represents the back button, my question is how to hard coding the back button in android studio?

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038479/android-go-back-to-previous-activity

Answer (score 0):

you can call the back button function like this:

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

this will call `onBackPressed()` method of current activity's parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `finish()` action in button clicklistener to back page.

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       finish();
    }
});
```